# DateTime.isAtSameMomentAs() is not working for me

Tags: flutter, datetime, comparison

I am trying to do a simple comparison between 2 DateTime dates. I am using the .isAtSameMomentAs() comparison but it is never true when both dates are 2021.07.02.

What am I doing wrong?

```
List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // kEvents is a linkedHashMap
    for (int i = 0; i < eventDoc.length; i++ ) {
      if (day.isAtSameMomentAs(eventDoc[i].eventDate)) {
        print(day);
      }
    }
}
```

In the image below the top date and the bottom dates are the dates I am trying to compare.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [compareTo method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html)

```
var temp = DateTime.now().toUtc();
 var date1 = DateTime.utc(temp.day,temp.year,temp.month);
//you can add today's date below
 var date2 = DateTime.utc(2,07,21);     
 if(date2.compareTo(date1)== 0){
   print('true');
 }else{
   print('false');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code

```
if (day.year == eventDate.year && day.day == eventDate.day && day.month == eventDate.month)
```

It works for now but I still think there is a better way.